# how to same result on textbox 2 when added value from select value in popup in javascript

Tags: javascript

help me, for the same result in textboxt result when i added value  on textbox nilai 1 from popup,
I am confused what event should I use in java script for my case.
I tried using onChange event but it didn't work

here is my code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method='post' action='' name='myF'>
Nilai 1 : <input  type=text name='nilai1' id='nilai1' size='20' onchange="sameresult()">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" NAME="My Window Name" title=" My title here "
onClick='javascript:window.open("pop_up.html","Ratting",
"width=550,height=170,left=150,top=200,toolbar=1,status=1,");'> Cari</a>
<br>
<br>

Result :<input type=text name='result' id='result' size='20'>
</form>
<script langauge="javascript">
function sameresult(){
var a = document.getElementById('nilai1');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
result.value = a.value;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

pop_up.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script langauge="javascript">
function post_value(s){
opener.document.getElementById('nilai1').value = s;
self.close();

}
</script>
<title>Popup</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border='1'>
<tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Value</td>
    <td>Action</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td><a href='#' onclick="post_value('200');">Select</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td><a href='#' onclick="post_value('300');">Select</a></td>
</tr>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say "I tried using onChange event but it didn't work", it's helpful to specify exactly what happened. Did you get an error in the console? Did absolutely nothing happen? Etc :)

Comment: @viona can be more clear? How said Bluendering...

Answer (score 0):

you can use onkeypress event like

```
Nilai 1 : <input  type=text name='nilai1' id='nilai1' size='20' onkeypress="sameresult()">
```

Comment: the textbox nilai1 value added from popup selected value, not from typing user